# Convertir objet en Array Object Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objeto

Estimado, quisiera convertir un objet en array objet
actualmente la data viene asi y no tiene , ni []

****esta data lo veo en HTML colocando  | json  PERO viene como Objet sin coma, lo saco de un *ngFor y *ngIf****

```
{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 }{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quisiera convertir así:

```
[{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 }]
```

ya que voy convertir en PIPE

```
{{  item | jsonconverarray}}  


import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'jsonconverarray'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any  {
       console.log(items)
   }
}
```

Comment: Buen día, el primer ejemplo que muestras, es una cadena de texto? o un objeto en sí? Ya que lo veo mal estructurado...

Comment: Algo como: `transform(obj: T): Array<T> { return [ obj ] }`. Siendo `T` el tipo de Objeto que esperas recibir. Has intentado algo?

Comment: @Cris223511.dev si viene como Objet sino como le puse en el html {{  items | json}}

ese es e resultado que me arroja, pero eso lo saco del *ngFor y *ngIF

Comment: @Cris223511.dev si acabo de modificar y agregar mi pregunta

Comment: @MauricioContreras si pero encierra por cada uno []  así:  
[ { "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 } ]
[ { "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TASUQ100", "HCOLNOM": "SULLUCHUCO QUISPE ANDERSON MIGUEL", "TOTAL_MES": 5100 } ]
[ { "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TOESJ100", "HCOLNOM": "ESPINOZA JAPA OSCAR RONAL", "TOTAL_MES": 4600 } ]

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero deberia ser así:

[ { "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 } ]
[ { "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TASUQ100", "HCOLNOM": "SULLUCHUCO QUISPE ANDERSON MIGUEL", "TOTAL_MES": 5100 } ,
[{ "RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TOESJ100", "HCOLNOM": "ESPINOZA JAPA OSCAR RONAL", "TOTAL_MES": 4600 } ]

Comment: Estás recorriendo un array de objetos. Y quieres volver a tener un array de objetos. No tiene sentido. Si ya tienes el array, no necesitas un proceso para obtener lo que ya tienes. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @MauricioContreras sii me arroja este error cuando lo coloco en mi tabla stg-table2

ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe? Find more

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo que sucede es que se debe guardar en tablas diferentes ejemplo hay azul, plomo , negro  se tiene que generar tabla de azul, plomo negro pero cada uno con su propia data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto que indicas no es valido:

```
  {
    "RINDTAB": 1,
    "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND",
    "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100",
    "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN",
    "TOTAL_MES": 5180
  },
  {
    "RINDTAB": 1,
    "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND",
    "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100",
    "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN",
    "TOTAL_MES": 5180
  }
```

Básicamente porque no puedes guardar un objeto separado por comas, eso no existe, lo que realmente existiria seria algo como esto:

```
[
  {
    "RINDTAB": 1,
    "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND",
    "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100",
    "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN",
    "TOTAL_MES": 5180
  },
  {
    "RINDTAB": 1,
    "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND",
    "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100",
    "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN",
    "TOTAL_MES": 5180
  }
]
```

Ya que un `array` puede guardar varios objetos dentro de si.

Lo unico que se me ocurre para que puedas obtener un resultado así es que el `JSON` venga mal formado desde el backend y que ademas no estes devolviendo directamente un `JSON` sino texto, de lo contrario ya tendrias problemas en el backend.

Por otro lado puedo observar que no tienes problemas al usar el objeto en angular ya que de lo contrario por estar mal formado te tendría que saltar miles de errores.

Esto me dice que quizás el `JSON` mal formado que tienes es una suposición tuya de como esta llegando el objeto, mas **NO como realmente esta llegando**, ya que como digo de lo contrario ni siquiera verías en pantalla:

```
[object Object]
```

Si no un montón de errores.

Así que sugiero que lo que esta pasando es que simplemente no estas accediendo de manera correcta a tus propiedades dentro del `JSON`, un ejemplo de ello es esta linea:

```
{{ item }}
```

`item` es el objeto completo de tu lista de objetos, por lo que estas intentando renderizar un objeto completo, a lo cual angular te especifica `[object Object]` debido a que angular no te va a imprimir nunca un objeto completo.

Si nada mas quieres imprimir el objeto completo asegúrate primero de parsearlo a un `string` por ejemplo:

```
{{ stringify(item) }}
```

Como no podemos usar `JSON.stringify` directamente en el objeto desde la vista, tendriamos que crear un método que permita pasar primero el objeto a un `string` en tu componente:

```
stringify(obj:any)
{
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

por otro lado si lo que quieres es usar la información de manera directa de cada `item` entonces accede a las propiedades del item:

```
{{ item.hdester }}
{{ item.RINDTAB }}
...
{{ item.TOTAL_MES }}
```

No hagas conversiones innecesarias, tu objeto no esta llegando en el formato que crees, no requieres convertirlo a un `array`, ya que **ya tienes un array de objetos**.

Answer (score 0):

no me queda claro si lo que quieres es un array de Jsons o un array de arrays con Json cada array. en fin, te planteo crear un array usando la data que te llega, iteramos con `Object.entries` y  `forEach` luego creamos el array a necesidad:

```js
const oldObj = [{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 },{"RINDTAB": 1, "hdester": "CENTRO ORIENTE_IND", "HCOLBT": "TYVEP100", "HCOLNOM": "VEGA PENADILLO YENSEN", "TOTAL_MES": 5180 }];

const newArray = []; 

Object.entries(oldObj).forEach(([i, obj]) => newArray.push({...obj}))

console.log(newArray)
```

si lo que quieres es un `[[{data1}], [{data2}]]` seria:

`Object.entries(oldObj).forEach(([i, obj]) => newArray.push([{...obj}]))`

Espero sea util.